# Open a Bootstrap Modal automatically after x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to have a **full screen bootstrap modal automatically pop open after x seconds** ( I also want it to work as a modal button on the page).  I have the full screen part working with a button, but when I apply any new javascript to it, it seems to disable the button all together and that's where I get stuck.

I've read the bootstrap modal documentation, w3 schools, etc.. I spent an hour on google and here, and all I can find is how to close it after x seconds which doesn't apply here.  This seems like something that would be very commonly used.. why do I feel like I'm searching for a needle in a haystack?

I tried adding this and it didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#fsModal").delay(2000).fadeIn(500);

});
```

Here's my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/nqa1sbko/

Any help is very appreciated!!

Comment: Add this in `ready`, `setTimeout(function() { $('#fsModal').modal('show'); }, 2000);` Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/nqa1sbko/1/)

Answer (score 5):

`fadeIn` will not work since the modal is not opened. You have to call the `modal` method with `show` option.

```
$('#fsModal').modal('show');
```

You can use it in a `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#fsModal').modal('show');
}, 2000);
```

If you want a `fadeIn` animation, just specify it in the modal options.

I edited your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nqa1sbko/2/

Comment: I'm also curious why this is down-voted, it's correct and I don't see any other way +1

Comment: Thanks!  This is how I wanted it to function!  The answer below works slightly different.. it has the blue screen open immediately then after x seconds the modal fades in, perhaps I worded my question wrong, but thats not what I was looking for.. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/nqa1sbko/3/),

You have to initialize the **model** without specifying the 'show' as a parameter, then after you can use **fadeIn** api.

```
$(function() {
    // .modal-backdrop classes
    $(".modal-fullscreen").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".modal-backdrop").addClass("modal-backdrop-fullscreen");
        }, 0);
    });
    $(".modal-fullscreen").on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        $(".modal-backdrop").addClass("modal-backdrop-fullscreen");
    });


    $('#fsModal').modal().fadeIn(1000); // Here x = 1000

});
```

Thanks